# overcome rpc endianness convert

Tags: c++, c, rpc, endianness

I want to assign unsigned char[8] to uint64 (c language) , pass this value with RPC and convert the uint64 back to unsigned char[8] with the same bytes order  (cpp language).
The problem is that the RPC may convert my uint64 endianness.
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can't you send the char array directly instead of converting it?

Comment: no, i can't change the RPC protocol :(

Comment: Which protocol are you using? Normally an RPC protocol should enable sending any data that's necessary.

Comment: I know that i can send array with this protocol but i need to use the uint64 field in order to pass this data.

Comment: Why? Why do you need to pass it as `uint64`? When it plainly isn't? Why can't you use `uchar[8]`? And which of the numerous RPC implementations are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the endiannes may change, you can still extract individual bytes from `uint64_t` portably, e.g.:

```
void to_bytes(uint64_t from, char* to) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof from; ++i, from >>= 8)
        to[i] = from & 0xff;
}
```

Alternatively, use reversing copy operations:

```
#ifdef BOOST_LITTLE_ENDIAN

    inline void xcopy(void* dst, void const* src, size_t n)
    {
        char const* csrc = static_cast<char const*>(src);
        std::reverse_copy(csrc, csrc + n, static_cast<char*>(dst));
    }

#elif defined(BOOST_BIG_ENDIAN)

    inline void xcopy(void* dst, void const* src, size_t n)
    {
        char const* csrc = static_cast<char const*>(src);
        std::copy(csrc, csrc + n, static_cast<char*>(dst));
    }

#endif

void to_bytes(uint64_t from, char* to) {
    xcopy(to, &from, sizeof from);
}

void from_bytes(char const* from, uint64_t* to) {
    xcopy(to, from, sizeof *to);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unit8_t data[8];
// fill the array, then ...
uint64_t carrier = data [0];
size_t position;
for (position = 1; position < 8; ++position) {
  carrier <<= 8;
  carrier |= data[position];
}
// ... on the other end
// variables of same type
position = 8;
while (position--) {
  data[position] = 0xFF & carrier;
  carrier >>= 8;
}
```

This should do it, since the **value** (so you don't have to worry about endianness) of `carrier` will be (hopefully) correctly transmitted by the RPC protocol.
Note the use of `uint8_t` instead of `char`. The later isn't guaranteed to be 1/8th of `uint64_t`.

The code *should* have well defined behaviour for both C and C++. For C++ you should rather use `std::array` instead of a raw array.